# Play 2 with Akka - Statelessness and scaling issues

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I thought that one of the advantages of using a stateless web framework such as Play was that a load-balancer could send requests to any node and not be concerned with which node receives the request. I am concerned about how Akka integration affects statelessness. By spawning an actor using the built-in system, aren't I potentially creating state that lives beyond a single request and is tied to a single instance of the application?

I think it would be fairly common to want to spawn an actor that lives beyond a single request and is accessible from multiple application instances. Is there a common pattern for accomplishing this?  Would it be necessary to use a remote actor system for spawning this actor or can the local built-in play system be used in some way?

Comment: Actors aren't inherently stateful.  One possibility is to spawn the actor on each node but keep the state in a distributed cache (e.g., Redis).

Comment: are you talking about a multi or single-node system?

Comment: @sourcedelica There are multiple play applications running. Each of these instances has its own JVM and actor system. Part of what I am trying to figure out is if it necessary for there to be at least one additional non-Play node.

Comment: @Ryan In the particular scenario I am imagining, a new actor is spawned as the result of a request.

Comment: Unless you need that actor to persist for the user's next request, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, I am specifically concerned about "an actor that lives beyond a single request".

Comment: IMO, that's likely a flaw in your design.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest setup you could have the stateful actor running at a known hostname/port and known actor path.  For example, it could be located at "akka.tcp://actorSystemName@10.0.0.1:2552/user/statefulActor".  Then on each of your play systems you would [look up this actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/remoting.html#Looking_up_Remote_Actors) and your stateless actors could send messages to it.  The stateful actor(s) could be running inside one of your play actor systems.  You wouldn't need to create a separate actor system.

The problem with the simple setup is that it's a single point of failure.  This may or may not be an issue for you.  For a more robust approach, see the [Cluster Singleton Pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/contrib/cluster-singleton.html).